# How to Add new jar to ATG ear without assembling or build

Tags: e-commerce, atg

Need to help to add jar to ATG Ear file without assembling or building the EAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new jar to existing already assembled ATG ear file add new Jar file to atglib folder and edit atg_bootstrap_ejb.jar manifest to add class path entry.

For exact steps please look at the below link

http://www.gingercart.com/Home/developer-handy/add-jar-to-atg-ear-without-assembling